# Touch screen ABS_X and ABS_Y wrong behavior

Tags: linux, arm, input, touch-screen

I have a 7" touch screen that I'm connecting to Linux. The touchscreen is recognized, but the behavior is wrong. I used the evtest utility to look at the events coming out of /dev/input/* and I see that the ABS_X and ABS_Y events are behaving strangely. When I tap on the screen it is registered, as an event, but immediately after ABS_X and ABS_Y show the maximum values, for example:

```
(ABS_X), value 1954
(ABS_Y), value 2451
(ABS_X), value 4095
(ABS_Y), value 4095
```

The device is reported as USBest Touchscreen. Has anyone run into behavior like this before, or have a possible solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible that the touch sensitivity needs to be adjusted? Maybe it detects some parasite capacitance at the edge. The real touch dominates, but as soon as you remove the finger, the corner is detected again. Is a touch detected through some sheets of paper? I'm pretty sure, this is no U&L question …

Comment: It is definitely a driver issue. I was able to get the touch screen working on a Raspberry Pi 2 B. I have a custom Linux platform made with yocto. I'm still investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to enable the hid multitouch driver when building the Linux kernel.

```
CONFIG_HID_MULTITOUCH=y
```